# How to avoid multiple calls to the same method c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# method , with asp on client side ,that is trigged at the moment a QR code is detected by the camera

```
protected void qrDetectado(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....
}
```

however in some cases, it detects the same QR code more than once, and calls the qrDetectado method multiple times, resulting in a lot of troubles with the databases, etcetera.

Is there a way to prevent multiplecalls to the same method at the same time

Edit: Yeah just to clarify a little bit more, i call the method via js, and if it has already read a code i dont need it to run once more.

Usually this kind of beheavior happens the first time it reads something, it has some kind of delay and the result is that i have like 3 or 4 times the same register in the database and some other issues, so, i only need to run it once, once it's done , keep reading

Comment: What you're looking for is called debouncing. There are many techniques, depending on how your backend is invoked. If it's in javascript (likely), have a search for javascript debouncing. Most frameworks have support for it. If not, it's trivial to implement.

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like you should be preventing the client side from calling twice, rather than preventing the serverside method from calling twice.

Comment: When you say "Is there a way to prevent multiplecalls to the same method at the same time" do you mean you have multiple threads concurrently calling this blocking method or do you mean that this method is non-blocking and the same thread calls it multiple times?

Answer (score -2):

One way you could solve this is by using a `lock`. This will block the calling thread while it attempts to acquire a lock on the object `_syncRoot`, only a single thread can lock the object at once. Once the code within the lock statement has completed the thread will release the lock and another thread can then enter that block of code. I have declared the object static so that it is the same object for all instances of the class. Please note that this will not lock across servers/processes.

```
   private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

   protected void qrDetectado(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        lock(_syncRoot)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
   }
```

You can read more about locking [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

If in fact you actually just want it called once, and only once, for the lifetime of the object, then you can combine a lock with a gate flag.

Comment: This won't prevent multiple executions of the method. Rather, it'll run them synchronously.

Comment: @Rob Incorrect.  OP is after _"prevent multiplecalls to the same method at the **same time**"_ for a question titled _"How to avoid multiple calls to the same method c#".  Now it is true it may be part of a larger problem but that's not what the OP is making in their request.

Comment: @MickyD Which is contradictory to the previous `calls the qrDetectado method multiple times, resulting in a lot of troubles` which is unrelated to running it in parallel. Since the question is slightly ambiguous, I've chosen to take the more likely interpretation that scanning the same QR code multiple times (regardless of whether or not it's parallel) is not desired.

Comment: @Rob did you read the question? "Is there a way to prevent multiplecalls to the same method at the same time?"

Comment: @Rob I would say it's much more likely to be a concurrency issue, than an issue with the method being able to be called more than once. It seems he is updating a database within this method, and therefore probably adding or updating multiple records incorrectly as the calls run concurrently. If that was the case then my solution would fix this problem (without considering locking across multiple servers/processes).

Comment: Debouncing will prevent multiple calls to qrDetectado from the client-side. Also, adding a lock on qrDetectado will prevent additional calls to qrDetectado while qrDetectado is being executed. Maybe OP should clarify. I personally thought he/she would seek a lock solution as opposed to debouncing.

Comment: You can immediately return from the failure to get a lock with `Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj, 0)`, or you can wait on the lock and then re-use results the first call memoised. Either or both can be applicable depending on just what one wants to happen for the subsequent attempts to call the method.